# How to get a report on document activity in a site

Tags: auditing, site-usage

I currently have a request to "find all documents that haven't been touched, ie opened, edited, moved, created, deleted, etc.) in the last 12 months." in WSS 3.0.

Now seeing as I never bothered to turn on auditing for the Site Collection in question, and my IIS/SharePoint logs don't go that far back is there any hope for extrapolating this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching this, I don't think there really is an answer.